# Как использовать sharp в регулярном выражении для mysql

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте. Возникла необходимость получить с помощью регулярного выражения строки с БД. Строки имеют формат:

> слово текста #12
>
> слово текста абзац #333

Написал регулярное выражение для php

```
(#\d+\s?)$
```

На ресурсе regex101 протестировал - работает как мне надо.

При попытке переписать регулярку под mysql (там насколько я разобрался синтаксис другой) - возникают проблеммы, а именно регулярка не работает должным образом - символ '#' не отрабатывает. Вот пример запроса:

```
SELECT id, `text` FROM `Text` WHERE `text` REGEXP "[\#]+[[:digit:]]+([[:blank:]]*)$"
```

Результат которого не удовлетворяет потребности.
Пробовал искать в google, и понял, что либо я не умею искать, либо нет четкого описания.
Спасибо за помощь, или подсказку, в каком направлении двигаться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where `text` rlike '.*#[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*$'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3a9f96761126b0a0a069ddf850a89d6)